# grep : '+' special character

Tags: grep

I did some simple tests with grep '+' and '*' special character

```
$ echo 'where wh+'> /tmp/toto
$ grep 'wh[e]\*' /tmp/toto
$ grep 'wh[e]*' /tmp/toto
where wh+
$ grep 'wh[e]+' /tmp/toto
$ grep 'wh+' /tmp/toto
$ grep 'wh[e]\+' /tmp/toto
where
$ grep -E 'wh[e]*' /tmp/toto
where wh+
$ grep -E 'wh[e]+' /tmp/toto
where wh+
```

From theses tests, non extended grep '+' (and '?') is not interpreted as a special character, in order to use it as a special character it must be escaped. As I read, grep uses Basic Regular Expressions (without -E option), in this case, special characters are defined here :
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03
and '?' '+' are not special characters for BRE.

But why does escaping non special character '+' in a BRE makes it special character?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a GNU extension. From the [`grep(1)` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html):

> In
>          GNU `grep`, there is no difference in available functionality between
>          basic and extended syntaxes.  In other implementations, basic regular
>          expressions are less powerful.  The following description applies to
>          extended regular expressions; differences for basic regular
>          expressions are summarized afterwards.

and further down

> **Basic vs Extended Regular Expressions**
>
> In basic regular expressions the meta-characters `?`, `+`, `{`, `|`, `(`, and `)`
>          lose their special meaning; instead use the backslashed versions `\?`,
>          `\+`, `\{`, `\|`, `\(`, and `\)`.

Answer (score 1):

At that link to the POSIX specification you gave, you can read:

> An ordinary character is a BRE that matches itself: any character in the supported character set, except for the BRE special characters listed in BRE Special Characters.
>
> The interpretation of an ordinary character preceded by a  ( '\' ) is undefined, except for:
>
> - The characters ')', '(', '{', and '}'
> - The digits 1 to 9 inclusive (see BREs Matching Multiple Characters)
> - A character inside a bracket expression

So basically, since `+` is an ordinary BRE character, the behaviour of `grep 'x\+'` is unspecified, some implementations like GNU `grep` treat it the same as `grep 'x\{1,\}'` (`grep -E 'x+'`), some the same as `grep 'x+'` some may treat is the same as `grep 'x\\+'` or anything else.

So if you mean to match the string `x\+` portably, you should write `grep 'x\\+'` (or `grep 'x[\]+'`, or `grep -F 'x\+'` or `grep -E 'x\\\+'` or `grep -E 'x[\][+]'`).

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite see which of the examples above to you seems to violate the defined behaviour?

No escaping of + changes the rules.